# Function that returns unique values for certain property in object array, in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

This is my data

```
$scope.Reports = [
  { Id: 1, Name: 'Report One', Year: 2016, Month: 5 },
  { Id: 2, Name: 'Report Core', Year: 2016, Month: 5 },
  { Id: 3, Name: 'Report Alpha', Year: 2016, Month: 3 },
  { Id: 4, Name: 'Report Moon', Year: 2015, Month: 5 },
  { Id: 5, Name: 'Report Sky', Year: 2015, Month: 2 }
];

$scope.desc = function (arr) {
            return $('min')
              ($('map')(arr, '-Year'));
        };
```

I am trying to retrieve the list of the `Year` values in descending order, so I can use them in an `orderBy` filter in AngularJs.

So for the data above, I'd want `[2016, 2015]`.

How can I get that?

Comment: I don't see how "the list of the Year values in descending order" would involve "min value of certain element in array".

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired result? Is it simply `[2016, 2015]` for the given data?

Comment: Yes, thats right. I want that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Angular has something specific to help with this, but in JavaScript it's fairly straight-forward: Determine the unique list of years, then sort them in descending order.

Here's an example doing it by building an object with keys for the years:

```js
var data = [
 { Id: 1, Name: 'Report One', Year: 2016, Month: 5 },
 { Id: 2, Name: 'Report Core', Year: 2016, Month: 5 },
 { Id: 3, Name: 'Report Alpha', Year: 2016, Month: 3 },
 { Id: 4, Name: 'Report Moon', Year: 2015, Month: 5 },
 { Id: 5, Name: 'Report Sky', Year: 2015, Month: 2 }
];
var years = getUnique(data, "Year").sort(function(a, b) {
  // Sorts numerically in descending order
  return b - a;
});

function getUnique(array, prop) {
  var obj = Object.create(null);
  array.forEach(function(entry) {
    obj[entry[prop]] = true;
  });
  return Object.keys(obj);
}

// Show result
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(years);
```

I split `getUnique` off into a function in case you need to reuse it for other similar things.

In an ES2015 environment, you might use `set` instead of an object (and arrow functions).

Comment: @NinaScholz: LOL, you're quite right, `-` will do the conversion, no need for the `+`s. In fact, the OP's data already has them as *numbers*, so using the `+` was doubly-wrong: We didn't need to convert, and if we had needed to, `-` would have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Use loadash in with angular.

```
_.reverse(_.sortedUniq(_.map(a,'Year')))
```